# solutions for Java JVM creation involving memory allocation do not fix my issue

Tags: java

I have a java virtual machine error on Windows 10. Nothing I have found (which is mostly gaming related) solve my Java failure to create the virtual machine. I have custom app add in for Enterprise Architect. The app to run is set as `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_161\bin\javaw.exe`  the arguments are set as `-classpath edu.vanderbilt.isis.face.v21.datamodel.ea.importexport.gui.jar;C:\Users\mi\Documents\EA\EA_Java_Bindings" -Djava.library.path=C:\Users\mi\Documents\EA\EA_Java_Bindings edu.vanderbilt.isis.face.v21.datamodel.ea.importexport.gui.EAImportExport --ea-project-file "$f" --ea-package-guid $P -import`

It has not made a difference what memory allocations I have tried to launch the VM

The application says it is a Java 7 application. I have tried uninstalling all java, and only installing java 7. and likewise for java 8 to try and get this app to launch with no success. I still have no success. Some I can see a second or so of execution, others absolutely nothing.

Comment: Please [format](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) your code/error message/etc. In the current form I can't understand what are the error messages.

Comment: Please explain clearly what you are trying to do, how you are trying to do it, and provide the full error messages, including complete stacktraces.

Comment: Also show us what you have tried so far. Which "memory allocations" have you tried and how.